# Putting several tweets in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, twitter, twitterapi-python

I am trying to download the last 10 tweets from BarackObama. However, when I try to put them into a dataframe, it only includes the 10th tweet (so only 1). Does someone know how to solve this problem? I tried the top part of the code first with just print instead of data, and then i got all 10 tweets, so I dont know where it goes wrong. I also dont get an error message.

```
user = 'BarackObama' 
posts = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name=user,).items(10)

for status in posts:
  if status.lang == 'en':
    data = {'User': [status.user.name],
        'Account name' ['@'+status.user.screen_name], 
        'Tweet': [status.text], 
        'Time': [status.created_at],
        'Nr of retweets': [status.retweet_count],
        'Nr of favorited': [status.favorite_count]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
   
df.head()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have to create a `list` of tweets, and then put them into `DataFrame`:

```
user = 'BarackObama' 
posts = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name=user,).items(10)
tweets = []

for status in posts:
  if status.lang == 'en':
    data = {'User': [status.user.name],
        'Account name' ['@'+status.user.screen_name], 
        'Tweet': [status.text], 
        'Time': [status.created_at],
        'Nr of retweets': [status.retweet_count],
        'Nr of favorited': [status.favorite_count]}
    tweets.append(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(tweets)
   
df.head()
```